# Positioning text over a canvas in a responsive div

Tags: html, css, canvas, responsive

This question has been asked and answered in portions, but I can't seem to find an answer in full. I have a responsive div in bootstrap, and I (1) want my canvas to display with the same position and dimensions, and (2) want my text to appear above the canvas.

```
<div class="col-md-9 content-wrapper>
    <canvas id="canvas" resize="true"></canvas>
    <p class="statement">Display this text over canvas</p>
</div>
```

css:

```
.statement{
     position:relative;
     top:50%;
     transform: translateY(-50%);
} 

#canvas{
     width:100%; height:100%;
}
```

Any advice? I know I'll need some sort of position css on the canvas, but I don't know what, and absolute positioning will give me problems with it's responsiveness. I'd also like to stay away from extra javascript for positioning, but if someone could explain a way that won't make it buggy, I'd be open to the suggestion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You place

`position: relative;`

On the background div.

Place

`Position: absolute;`

On the foreground div and position with `top, bottom, left, right`. The foreground container will work relative to the background, meaning it is responsive, if you set the width of the foreground using %

Comment: is there any chance you know why this results in the text (over the canvas) fading a little bit? I would imagine maybe something to do with alpha or something, but not totally sure.

Comment: I couldn't say without seeing a Fiddle or a screenshot. It sounds like you might be using Opacity? Opacity applies to children elements, meaning the foreground might be inheriting the opacity? Just a guess...